# Add XmlElement to XmlElement [] dynamically

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add XmlElement to XmlElement[] array dynamically.

Am trying like this below.But in case of multiple Elements not sure how to add..

Need to create multiple XmlElement based on criteria and add to this Array

Please help me out

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var xelement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("DocId");
        xelement.InnerText = "Test";

        var xelemArray = new XmlElement[]
        {
            xelement
        };
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a list

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        var xelement1 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("DocId");
        var xelement2 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("DocId");
        var xelement3 = xmlDoc.CreateElement("DocId");

        xelement1.InnerText = "Test1";
        xelement2.InnerText = "Test2";
        xelement3.InnerText = "Test3";

        List<XmlElement> xmlElementsList  = new List<XmlElement>();
        xmlElementsList.Add(xelement1);
        xmlElementsList.Add(xelement2);
        xmlElementsList.Add(xelement3);

        var xelemArray = xmlElementsList.ToArray<XmlElement>();
```