# C# Adding element to collection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add an XmlElement to XmlElement[] but this seems to be impossible.

the errormessage:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlElement' to
>   'System.Xml.XmlElement[]'
>
> The XmlElement[] object does not have an Add or Insert function

so how can I do this?

*Update with code:*

This part is created from an XSD
        private System.Xml.XmlElement[] anyField;

```
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any
    {
        get
        {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to create the object and add a UniversalShipment to the Any collection.

```
    UniversalInterchangeBody body = new UniversalInterchangeBody();
    UniversalShipmentData shipmentData = new UniversalShipmentData();
    XmlElement universalShipmentXML = SerializeToXmlElement(shipmentData);
    body.Any = universalShipmentXML;

    public static XmlElement SerializeToXmlElement(object o)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        using (XmlWriter writer = doc.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
        {
            new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o);
        }
        return doc.DocumentElement;
    }
```

Comment: please share some code how you tried?

Comment: Can you post the code that generate this error ?

Comment: you have to add elements at indexes of the array.

Comment: already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125311/add-xmlelement-to-xmlelement-dynamically

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding values to a C# array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202813/adding-values-to-a-c-sharp-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed a copy of [Add XmlElement to XmlElement [] dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125311/add-xmlelement-to-xmlelement-dynamically) sorry for this!

as for the solution to my code in this case:

```
var uShipmentCollection = new UniversalShipmentData[]
{
    shipmentData
};
```

Thanks for the duplicate reference Gusdor!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a List.

```
List<XmlElement> elements = new List<XmlElement>();
elements.Add(xamlElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

An array is pre-sized with default elements in all entries of the array.  You cannot re-size the array by inserting/adding (if you do want to do this use a `List<T>` instead).  Otherwise simply set the value of an entry at a specific index:

```
array[index] = value
```